# Strange bug: uncommenting an NSPredicate within an NSFetchedResultsController will empty the UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a strange bug: if I uncomment my `NSPredicate`, the resulting `UITableView` is empty.

My data Model is the following:
        Category <-->> Feed <-->> Post

I am fetching the `Post`s. `Post.feed` is a `Post`'s `Feed`. `Feed` has an `rss` `NString` property.

Here's the code:

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

        // Set up the fetched results controller if needed.
        if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {
            // Create the fetch request for the entity.
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
            NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:_globalMOC];
            [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

            // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
            NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
            NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
            [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

            NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"feed.rss == %@",  _detailItem.rss];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

            // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
            // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
            NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
            [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                managedObjectContext:_globalMOC
                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                           cacheName:nil];
            self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

            self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

            NSError *error = nil;

            if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate.
                // You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful
                // during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert
                // panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
                //
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }

        }

        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
```

I only see results if I uncomment the `NSPredicate`. I tried with `LIKE`, `==`, `=`, with double and single quotes around `%@`...

The best would be to directly compare the `Feed` object...

Anyone can help me?

Comment: why don't you compare the feed object then? And is `_detailItem` actually set when this method is called?

Comment: Like Wain said, you should try to compare feed object first. What type is _detailItem.rss?

Comment: As said above, I tried all: comparing NSStrings, NSManagedObjects, adding or removing quotes, ... _detailItem is set: it is the Feed which Posts I want to filter. It is a syntax problem.

Comment: I also NSLogged around to ensure _detailItem.rss and feed.rss point to the same NSString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586124/why-do-i-have-to-comment-out-my-nspredicate-to-have-nsfetchedresultscontroller-p).

The problem was that the `NSFetchedResultsController` was initialized once before the `_detailItem` was even set.